# Cannot find Bigquery connector in Tableau Desktop

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-desktop

I cannot find the Bigquery connector in my Tableau desktop.
I've read many solution in internet, still I didn't find the answer.

Is it because my Tableau is free version?

[image: 1]

I did googling and watch video, yet didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Tableau Public, you can easily get the connector in Tableau Desktop

[image]

Now, if you are a student or Know someone you can get a Tableau desktop License
from here : https://www.tableau.com/academic/students

Comment: I think you're right. gonna try the desktop one, thanks for your answer

Comment: please mark my answer as solved, help others